# Clustering for language dialects

Tags: nlp, clustering, open-source

I have a codebase in a programming language, various projects written by different people. The language is quite complex, so people use it in different styles, partially based on personal preference and knowledge, but also based on the problem they want to solve. I would like to discover language dialects through some language processing tool. My limited exposure to data mining says that this is a problem of clustering.

What open source software would you recommend for this task?